# Выполнение системных команд из-под Java (Runtime.exec)

Tags: java, cmd, exec, runtime

Нуждаюсь в пояснении синтаксиса "системных команд" для параметра метода **exec()**.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe");
```

Что, например, в данном случае значит мета-символ **\c** и параметр **start**. Понятно, что запускает командную строку, но почему просто не **cmd.exe**? Ведь некоторые процессы запускаются просто по пути. Где смогу найти полное руководство по синтаксису? Документация **Oracle** молчит по этому поводу...

*Заранее спасибо)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это команды консоли windows (нажмите Пуск-выполнить-введите "cmd"), которые запускает виртуальная java машина посредством Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...).

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe");
```

При такой комбинации команд запускается отдельное окно cmd.

cmd - командный интерпретатор

start - команда запуска чего-либо в отдельном окне

```
C:\Windows\System32>cmd /?
Запуск новой копии интерпретатора команд Windows.

CMD [/A | /U] [/Q] [/D] [/E:ON | /E:OFF] [/F:ON | /F:OFF] [/V:ON | /V:OFF]
    [[/S] [/C | /K] строка]

/C      Выполнение указанной команды (строки) с последующим завершением.
```

Фактически мы делаем так:

1. запустить интерпретатор cmd
2. запустить в нем команду start, которая откроет отдельное окно cmd
3. завершить работу cmd

P.S. Если бы предполагалось что программа на java должна выполнятся не в Windows а например в Linux, то команды были бы другими.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Ещё интересует вопрос: можно ли указать параметр запуска cmd.exe в текущем примере, например, открыть в свёрнутом режиме?

Comment: Конечно, у команды start есть ключ `MIN`. `cmd /c start /MIN cmd.exe`

Comment: Огромное спасибо)